# How to host WCF Data Service (OData) in IIS7?

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7, wcf-data-services, odata

Does anyone know how to host a WCF Data Service (or OData) inside IIS7? I'm seeing lots of articles about hosting WCF, but none specific to WCF Data Service.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hosting a **WCF Data Service** in IIS is actually the default option.

Its a pretty easy 3 step process:

1. Create a new **WebApplication** project (or re-use an existing one)
2. Add a **WCF Data Service** to the project
3. Deploy to your IIS server

Step 3 is just the standard process for deploying a WebApplication to IIS.

Answer (score 1):

A **WCF Data Service** is just a WCF (REST) service, with some additional out-of-the-box functionality added in.

It has a `*.svc` file and all - it will be hosted very much the same as a "regular" WCF REST service.

So all the articles you see about WCF REST should really apply to WCF Data Services as well - or are you experiencing some difficulties with something specifically??