# Expose a WCF Data Service with a "WCF Service Application" project

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I have a solution structured like this

```
Solution  
   |  
   +-- DataAccessLayer (EF Model)  
   +-- ODataProject    (Contains MyODataService that inherits from DataService)  
   +-- SelfHost        (Hosts the ODataProject.MyODataService in a console app)
```

I need to add an project (call it IISHost) that will host the project in IIS (For some authentication and authorization testing).

Most of the WCF Data Services examples I see use an *ASP.NET Web Application*.  I could use that, but it seems messy.  I am not making a web page, and much that goes with an *ASP.NET Web Application* project seems centered around web sites (it has two web pages and a master page by default).

I would like to use a *WCF Service Application* project as that seems more focused on what I need.  But I can't figure out how to wire it up to my ODataProject.MyODataService class.

If this is possible, could someone please post how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

When you add the WCF Service Application project to your solution you will see that the following files are added:

1. IService1.cs
2. Service1.svc

Rename these to something meaningful for your project.

It's a good idea to keep the service interface in a separate file to the code that actually implement the functionality.

The interface (method names plus input and return params) for any public methods that you want to expose through WCF should be defined in the IService1.cs file. The Service.svc file has a "code-behind" file called Service1.svc.cs. This is where you code the actual implementation of the methods you defined in IService1.cs

Right-click on the Service1.svc file and choose "View Markup". You will then see how your code gets linked into IIS.

Right-click your new WCF Service Application, choose properties / Web. In the "servers" section choose "Use Local IIS Web Server". Make sure your code is copied to a virtual directory. If you have a metadata exchange point (MEX) endpoint configured in your services web.config you should be able to "browse" to the .svc file in IE and get the service description.

Sorry if the above is explaining what you already know but I wasn't exactly sure what it is you're missing. Please feel free to give more detail to the question if needed and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this is not quite what I was looking for.  I am using OData (WCF Data Services) not WCF Services.  And my OData stuff is in a different project in the solution.  I need a way to reference it from the WCF Service Application project and get it to run in IIS.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I hadn't heard of WCF Data Services and OData. Having read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937697 I've added to the growing list of technologies that I need to read up on!

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764469/how-to-host-wcf-data-service-odata-in-iis7